# which programmatically steps are needed for server code to reach the multiple client appraoch

Tags: android

I want to build an app which will transmit data(Long, lat, timestamp and SSID) every 60 seconds to the server in the background when the location changed. The data will be stored the in the database server and in case of request the server will send response back to the user. I want to implement that by using HttpURLConnection api on the client side which programmatically steps are needed for  server code to reach the multiple  client appraoch? I will use PHP script Language on the server side too.

Comment: I would imagine a simple multi-threaded socket approach would work just fine.... the trickiest part will be designing the server-side client handling of the data...

Comment: I thought rest and Socket are different approaches.